# Why isn't spidev showing up in /dev/?

Tags: spi

I'm trying to do a spi loopback test with a raspberry pi 3 model B+ with kernel patched with RT_PREEMPT.

This is the loopback test being attempted: [Link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#spi-overview%23troubleshooting)

To run the test you must specify a path such as /dev/spidev0.0.  I have no such file in /dev:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev | grep spi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

The kernel version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r
4.9.80-rt62-v7+
```

I think the settings in /boot/config.txt are what they are supposed to be and I've rebooted a few times since setting it this way:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/boot $ cat config.txt | grep spi
dtparam=spi=on
```

There seems to be all sorts of spi stuff in the loaded device tree:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree | grep 'spi'
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /soc has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /soc/vchiq has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /soc/gpiomem has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /soc/local_intc has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /soc/axiperf has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /memory has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /axi/vc_mem has a reg or ranges property, but no unit name
<stdout>: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /axi/vc_mem
<stdout>: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /axi/vc_mem
        spi = "", "", "", "!status";
        spi2 = "/soc/spi@7e2150c0";
        spi0 = "/soc/spi@7e204000";
        spidev1 = "/soc/spi@7e204000/spidev@1";
        spi0_gpio35 = "/soc/gpio@7e200000/spi0_gpio35";
        spi = "/soc/spi@7e204000";
        spi0_pins = "/soc/gpio@7e200000/spi0_pins";
        spi0_gpio7 = "/soc/gpio@7e200000/spi0_gpio7";
        spi1 = "/soc/spi@7e215080";
        spi1_gpio16 = "/soc/gpio@7e200000/spi1_gpio16";
        spi2_gpio40 = "/soc/gpio@7e200000/spi2_gpio40";
        spi0_cs_pins = "/soc/gpio@7e200000/spi0_cs_pins";
        spidev0 = "/soc/spi@7e204000/spidev@0";
            spi0_gpio35 {
            spi0_pins {
            spi0_gpio7 {
            spi1_gpio16 {
            spi2_gpio40 {
            spi0_cs_pins {
        spi@7e204000 {
            compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-spi";
            spidev@1 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                spi-max-frequency = <0x7735940>;
            spidev@0 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                spi-max-frequency = <0x7735940>;
        spi@7e215080 {
            compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-aux-spi";
        spi@7e2150c0 {
            compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-aux-spi";
        spi2 = "/soc/spi@7e2150c0";
        spi0 = "/soc/spi@7e204000";
        spi1 = "/soc/spi@7e215080";
```

Any hints?

--Edit after some good hints in the comments --

I think I forgot to copy the /lib/modules/4.9.80-rt62-v7+/* files from the host where I built the kernel to the target.

```
adam@hostWhereKernelWasCrossCompiled:~/rtBuild_4_9$ find -iregex '.*spidev.*'
./lib/modules/4.9.80-rt62-v7+/kernel/drivers/spi/spidev.ko

pi@raspberrypi:/lib $ find -iregex '.*spidev.*'
./modules/4.14.34-v7+/kernel/drivers/spi/spidev.ko
```

No modules for 4.9.80-rt62-v7+ (the active kernel) are installed on the target.

Comment: look in the output of `dmesg` for references to SPI

Comment: dmesg | grep -i 'spi' returns nothing

Comment: how about `lsmod | grep -i spi`

Comment: lsmod returns nothing at all.  Even without piping it into grep.

Comment: oh, well, that is odd - where did you get this `kernel patched with RT_PREEMPT` ... edit: never mind - found it

Comment: I built it :) I recall there was something about 'modularizing' stuff in the  menuconfig tool and I didn't do it.

Comment: oh, so you've built a kernel without modules - have you included all the drivers you need inside the kernel? (e.g., spidev and another one whose name escapes me)

Comment: adam@hostWhereKernelWasBuilt:~/projects/raspberrypi/rtKernel/rtBuild_4_9$ find -iregex '.*spidev.*'
./lib/modules/4.9.80-rt62-v7+/kernel/drivers/spi/spidev.ko

Comment: the `spi` modules in the standard kernel are: `spi-bcm2835` and `spidev` (these two are loaded when you change config.txt as you have done) - but then there's also `spi-bcm2835aux` `ad714x-spi` `adxl34x-spi` `psxpad-spi` `bmp280-spi` `mmc_spi` `of_mmc_spi` `spi-nor` `arizona-spi` `cxd2880-spi` - not sure if you'd need any of those as well

Comment: Hang on, you have a `lib/modules/` folder - yet you say you didn't "modularize"?

Comment: Maybe somethings were modularized and others were not.  You know what though, I think I copied the wrong modules or forgot to copy them into the target machine.  I'm editing the question now to show my new findings.

Answer (score 2):

/dev/spidev wasn't showing up because files were missing in /lib/modules.

I cross compiled the rt kernel and when I was installing it on the target I forgot to copy the /lib/modules/4.9.80-rt62-v7+ and /lib/firmware.

After copying the contents of those directories onto the taget and rebooting /dev/spidev exists!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev | grep spi
spidev0.0
spidev0.1
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say copy the files into "target" - what is target?